# Rewrite array key after pull session item

Tags: arrays, laravel

```
        $items = session('table'.$id_meja);
        $count = count($items);
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
            if($items[$i]['id_items'] == $id_item){
                
                session()->pull('table'.$id_meja.'.'.$i);
                dd(session()->all());
            }
        }
```

It can remove the item, but the result is like this

```
"table4" => array:2 [▼
0 => array:6 [▶]
2 => array:6 [▶]
```

]
How to change the key 2 into 1

Answer (score 0):

if you need to re index this array , you can use  :- array_values($array)